# can someone help me with this linear algebra problem?

Tags: linear-algebra

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2x2Z6.png)

Determine whether or not S is a subspace of P, . If S is a subspace, compute dim S. the set of all functions that satisfy this equation 
15. f(0)=f(1)

my attempt

obviusly this is a subspace , that is not problem  but for me is a n+1 dimensional subspace ,but in the back of the book it says  is n dimensional (where n is the number of the highest degree polynomial) i dont get why is of dimension n ,if you have a n degree poly that you need n+1 elements to form a base

Comment: The point here is that your elements can't all be independent if your polynomial satisfies $f(0) = f(1)$; if the polynomial is $\sum_i p_ix^i$, then $p_1+p_2+\ldots+p_n=0$.

Answer (score 1):

If you were talking about the whole space $P_n$, then it would be an $n+1$-dimensional subspace. However, notice that this space is a *subspace* of $P_n$, meaning it could have anywhere from $0$ to $n+1$ basis elements spanning it. In particular, we are restricted in some way: while $P_n$ includes any old polynomial with degree at most $n$, we require furthermore that $f(0) = f(1)$.

This restriction, as you have found out, means that some polynomials are excluded: for example $f(x) = 2x$ is not included if $n \geq 1$. To find the dimension of this subspace, we write out what $f(0) = f(1)$ actual means: if $f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + \cdots a_n x^n$, then this constraint means that $a_0 = a_0 + a_1 + \cdots + a_n$, or equivalently, $a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n = 0$. That means two things: first, I can arbitrarily pick what $a_0$ is, i.e. $a_0$ is a free variable, and second, I can pick at most $n - 1$ of $a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n$ freely. In other words, if I pick $n-1$ of those (say $a_1$ through $a_{n-1}$), the last one must be chosen so that the sum is zero (in this example, $a_n = -a_1 - a_2 - \cdots -a_{n-1}$. So that means I can choose $n$ elements freely: $a_0$, and any $n-1$ elements of $a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_{n-1}$. This justifies why the number of basis elements is $(n - 1) + 1 = n$, which also corresponds to the dimension of this subspace.